# Returning value from get function with content script

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to make a function to return data from a worker but it doesn't seem to work, how should I do this?

```
function getExample()
{
    worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({contentScript:
        "var testText = document.getElementsByClassName('exampleElement')[0].children[1].innerHTML;" +
        "self.port.emit('test', testText);"
    });
    worker.port.on('test', function(test) {return testText;});
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work" does not really describe your problem. How is it not working?

Comment: I don't get a value in return from getExample(). If I return a variable outside worker.port.on, i get the value from the function but not when the return is inside it.

Answer (score 2):

The `port.on` API is pretty much the same concept as a DOM event listener. You cannot simply return something from the listener function and expect it to propagate to outer function. It isn't even guaranteed your listener function will be called synchronously. Your current function is equivalent to:

```
function getExample() {
    worker.port.on('test', function(testText) {return testText;});
    return undefined;
}
```

You need to provide a callback function and have your code assume that things are asynchronous:

```
function getExample(callback) {
    /* ... */
    worker.port.on('test', function(testText) { callback(testText); });
    // or shorter:
    worker.port.on('test', callback);
}
```

PS: I just noticed that your `on` function has a parameter named `test`, but the function body uses the undefined `testText`. This is an issue, too, but an unrelated one and likely only introduced when you simplified your real code to fit into a question here.